# How to get the real row's height in a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, row, height

I'm using a TabControl to insert DataGridView in each tab. The first Column of the DGV is a ButtonCollumn and I'm trying to change the padding of all cell in this first column in each DGV by using the row's height (so that all the button can be the same size), but the height is different from the one showned. It works correctly for the first Tab, but not the others.

I have tried to do the change the padding at different place in my code, in case the height may somehow not be set yet, but nothing changed.

I have set the  grid's RowTemplate to a minimum. This same minimum is the one that i see when i look at the height of each row of any other tab than the first. So in the end, the padding is wrong and the button oversized.

I thought it might be because of the DGV not being drawn at that moment so the size wouldn't be set yet, but the first Tab makes me believe otherwise.

Here's my code for the padding, if it can be of any help:

```
For each tp As TabPage In  Me.TabControl1.TabPages

    Dim dgv As DataGridView = tp.Controls(0)

        For each row as DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
            dim h As integer = row.Height
            row.Cells(0).Style.Padding = New Padding(12,
                                                     Math.Ceiling((h -24)/2),
                                                     12,
                                                     Math.Floor((h -24)/2))
            row.Cells(0).Value = h     ' For debbuging purpose
    Next
Next
```

**Edit:**

When I create the DGV, the `AutoSizeRowsMode` is set to `AllCells`, `WrapMode` to `True`. (If this info can help)

Comment: Try with `DataGridView1.AutoResizeRows()` after you have set it's `DataSource` (or otherwise filled it).

Comment: @Jimi Wherever i put it, nothing changes.

Comment: Set `AutoSizeRowsMode` to `None` in the Designer, then use `AutoResizeRows()` when you first show the DGV.

Comment: "It works correctly for the first Tab, but not the others." - Likely due to the fact that other other tabpages have not created their controls yet.  See if applying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50119854/2592875) helps.

Comment: @TnTinMn Worked like a charm! Thanks! :)